# trigger d3.js update when data changes using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am using Angular.js to create some visualizations. I got a directive for a bar chart that looks like this:

```
angular.module('MissionControlApp').directive('d3Bars', ['d3', function(d3) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            label: "=",
            onClick: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, iElement) {
            var svg = d3.select(iElement[0])
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%");

            // on window resize, re-render d3 canvas
            window.onresize = function() {
                return scope.$apply();
            };
            scope.$watch(function(){
                    return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
                }, function(){
                    return scope.render(scope.data);
                }
            );

            // watch for data changes and re-render
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVals) {
                return scope.render(newVals);
            }, true);

            // define render function
            scope.render = function(data){
                if(data === undefined){
                    return;
                }
                // remove all previous items before render
                svg.selectAll("*").remove();

                // setup variables
                var width, height, max;
                var margin = {top: 5, right: 30, bottom: 10, left: 150};

                width = d3.select(iElement[0])[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
                height = (scope.data.length * 35) + margin.top + margin.bottom;
                max = 100;

                // set the height based on the calculations above
                svg.attr('height', height);

                var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 100])
                    .range([0, width]);

                var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.user; }))
                    .rangeBands([0, height], 0.1, 0.35);

                // var color = d3.scale.category20c();
                var color = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 25, 50, 75, 100])
                    .range(["#51b75d", "#90eb9d","#ffff8c","#f5c93f","#c45c44"])
                    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .innerTickSize(-(height-5));

                //create the rectangles for the bar chart
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("fill", function(d){return color(d.value); })
                    .on("click", function(d){return scope.onClick({item: d});})
                    .attr("height", y.rangeBand()) // height of each bar
                    .attr("width", 0) // initial width of 0 for transition
                    .attr("x", margin.left) // half of the 20 side margin specified above
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.user); }) // height + margin between bars
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("width", function(d){ return d.value/(max/width); });

                svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("y", function(d){return y(d.user) + (y.rangeBand() / 2);})
                    .attr("x", 150)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("dx", -5)
                    .text(function(d){return d[scope.label];});

                svg.append("g")
                    .selectAll("valueLabels")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("y", function(d){return y(d.user) + (y.rangeBand() / 2);})
                    .attr("x", function(d){return x(d.value) + margin.left;})
                    .attr("dx", 5)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .text(function(d){return parseFloat(d.value).toFixed(0) + "%";})
                    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .attr("fill-opacity", 1);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axisHorizontal")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" +  margin.left + "," + (height-margin.bottom) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

This defines a "onClick" event which in turns sets a piece of data in my controller like so:

```
vm.d3OnClick = function(item){
        // item {user: konrad.sobon, value: 26}
        SetUserData(item);
    };

    function SetUserData (item) {
        var allData = vm.selectedWorkset.onOpened;
        var userData = [];
        allData.forEach(function (d) {
            if(d.user === item.user){
                userData.push({
                    name: d.user,
                    value: (d.opened * 100) / (d.closed + d.opened),
                    createdOn: d.createdOn
                })
            }
        });
        console.log("SettingData to: ", userData);
        vm.userData = userData;
    }
```

vm.userData is being used to construct a different chart which looks like this:

```
angular.module('MissionControlApp').directive('d3WorksetUser', ['d3', function(d3) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            label: "=",
            onClick: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, iElement) {
            var svg = d3.select(iElement[0])
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%");

            // on window resize, re-render d3 canvas
            window.onresize = function() {
                return scope.$apply();
            };
            scope.$watch(function(){
                    return angular.element(window)[0].innerWidth;
                }, function(){
                    return scope.render(scope.data);
                }
            );

            // watch for data changes and re-render
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVals) {
                return scope.render(newVals);
            }, true);

            // define render function
            scope.render = function(data){
                if(data === undefined){
                    return;
                }
                // remove all previous items before render
                svg.selectAll("*").remove();

                // setup variables
                var width, height;
                var margin = {top: 5, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 25};

                width = d3.select(iElement[0])[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
                height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // set the height based on the calculations above
                svg.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

                var parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ').parse;

                var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
                var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5);

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(9);

                var line = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) + margin.left; })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.date = parseDate(d.createdOn);
                    d.value = +d.value;
                });

                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
                y.domain([0, 100]);

                // Add the valueline path.
                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("d", line)
                    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

                // Add the X Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axisMain")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                // Add the Y Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axisMain")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                    .call(yAxis);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I am debugging this in Chrome i can see that my click events trigger the appropriate methods on my controller and that vm.userData gets set to new data, but my line chart doesn't update...basically nothing happens. Is there something obvious that I am missing that will make the click event in one chart refresh/redraw the other chart?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Workset on Opened</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <d3-bars data="vm.DataOpened" label="vm.d3Label" on-click="vm.d3OnClick(item)"></d3-bars>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-group" id="userDetail">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#userDetail" data-target="#collapseUserDetail">
                <h4 class="panel-title">User detail info.</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseUserDetail" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <d3-workset-user data="vm.userData"></d3-workset-user>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both charts draw fine on the first load, but then the second one never updates.

[image]

Here's a console log to support that:

[image]

Where: Setting data to: is fired by the controller when i first get the data from the server and set it.
Then my `scope.$watch` fires twice in response to that. I think the first one is when data is still `undefined` and then again after it was resolved.
Finally there are events associated with mouse click and data being updated but as you can see `watch` never re-fires.

Comment: Have you checked if your `scope.$watch('data', ...` actually works? Sorry if you have already checked this. Maybe even add a `scope.$apply` there

Comment: I think it works. I put a console.log() into it, and it fires once when the page is loaded. Then it never fires again.

Comment: I think it should fire when data gets updated, right?

Comment: That's the idea. So it fires on the original page load which is fine because I think that's when the data get's set for the first time. But then I set that same variable vm.UserData again from a onClick event and it doesn't fire. Have a look at the console log

Comment: Could you try adding `scope.$apply();` before `return scope.render`?

Comment: I get `[$rootScope:inprog]` error when I do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145724/discussion-between-konrad-and-jeff-huijsmans).

Comment: Then try `$timeout(function() {})`, to make Angular do it automatically when it's not still in progress. (Note, leave the function empty)

Comment: Where would I put the timeout? keep in mind that I am a bit of a js noob. Only been looking at js for the last 3 weeks or so...

Comment: No problem! Sorry for taking so long again. Put the `$timeout(function() {})` BEFORE `return scope.render(newVals);`, but INSIDE the `scope.$watch`. Let me know! I'll try to come by regularly :)

Comment: well I added it inside the link function and set the interval to 1000. It seems to be working just fine now. so basically I don't need watch now...right? I mean from what I just read about $timeout it triggers `scope.$apply` or more precisely the $digest method. That should take care of watching for changes right?

Comment: also, interval was a great suggestion, thank you for that. Please post an answer and I will get you the bounty. I just can't stop wondering why wasn't the binding with $watch working on its own. What could be the reason?

Comment: No problem! See my answer for an explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second `$watch` function to the following:

```
// watch for data changes and re-render
scope.$watch('data', function(newVals) {
    $timeout(function() { scope.render(newVals) });
}, true);
```

I would still keep the `$watch` and use `$timeout` instead of `$interval` so your application doesn't waste digest cycles.

This happens because scope.$watch gets triggered inside a digest cycle, and because angular is event-based, changing a value inside the cycle doesn't re-trigger the watches. A `$timeout` with `0 ms` timeout schedules another digest cycle after the current one. Basically (iirc), `$timeout` is a `setTimeout` with a `scope.$apply` inside of it.